# Comic book project using all open source apps

Tags: license, legal

I wanted to know if it is ok to display the Ubuntu logo in my new comic book. I used Ubuntu, Gimp, and Inkscape and wanted to promote them in my project.

Comment: This site is not the site in where Canonical exists, you would have to contact Canonical and ask for permission to use the Ubuntu logo in your project.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the legal use case for the Ubuntu logo, and not an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: @ThomasW. It's certainly a legal issue but it's completely answerable.

Answer (score 4):

"Ubuntu" has trademark protections and the logo has trademark and copyright. Ubuntu has a fairly loose [trademark policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/intellectual-property-policy) which does explicitly allow most things for non-commercial use as long as you're not hinting that Canonical or Ubuntu are endorsing you, and that you follow their [logo guidelines](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/ubuntu-logo).

If you want explicit permission (and I think it would be silly *not* to), [talk to Canonical](https://forms.canonical.com/trademark/). At the very least they should be able to give you a written confirmation of what I'm saying.

Most big projects will have trademarks on their logo and name for software use. Use of them is usually okay in a non-commercial, non-endorsement role but again, it costs nothing but a few minutes to check.

Comment: Don't we have another question about this?